# Rvest getting an specific text from html_node

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

[image]

I want to extract only "Beech Valley Solutions - "

When I run

```
html_nodes('li') %>% 
  html_nodes(".flexbox.empLoc") %>%  
  html_text()
```

All the information comes out. "Beech Valley Solutions - Atlanta, GA Today 24hr"

Comment: Please add the HTML as text and not as a screenshot, as images are not searchable text

Comment: Can we have the url for testing?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way of doing **scraping** using rvest.
Instead of passing css selector item in html_nodes(), you can pass xpath within html_nodes().Just an example below -

```
page %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='series-matches']/div[20]/div[3]/div[1]/a[1]/span")
```

Reference:
https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

x path is easier to fetch -

1. Right click the section for which you want to fetch xpath.
2. Select inspect code from the drop down.                                         3. html page will appear to the right side, from which click the right click and press Copy option.
3. Drop will appear from which select "Copy xpath".
4. Ctrl V (Paste) the xpath within html_nodes(xpath = "xpath here").        I hope this will help you.